# Secure controller by name in the security.yml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

How I can use the controller name in the security.yml to protect a specific controller.

Something like:

```
access_control:
    - { controller: my.controller.name, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it via name? Why path is not enough?

Comment: you can use [`@Security`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) annotation to do that

Comment: The controller is accessed by different path, based on configurations. 
Want to keep the security.yml simple. 
Cant add annotation because the controller is in a bundle installed by composer.

Comment: write an event listener then. It will check controller name and needed roles

Answer (score 0):

```
public function helloAction($name)
{
    // The second parameter is used to specify on what object the role is tested.
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

    // Old way :
    // if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    //     throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('Unable to access this page!');
    // }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This will throw a 403 and will not redirect to the login page if I remember it correctly.